# Ruby Threads and MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, ruby, multithreading

I'm trying the Ruby Threads, i have a simple script that need to iterate a json for getting certain data, all works fine but in one moment the shell shows:

```
`_query': This connection is in use by: #<Thread:0x00007f9c73973eb8@thread.rb:62 sleep> (Mysql2::Error)
```

How can i close that connection that i need for the data.

And the most important, the Threads are actually in the right way?

This is the script, it will run with a crontab:

```
require 'firebase'
require 'conekta'
require 'json'
require 'savon'
require "crack"
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'  #from_xml 
require 'nokogiri'
require 'xmlsimple'
require 'mysql2'

class Cron  

    def generate_activation_code(size = 10)
        charset = %w{ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z}
        (0...size).map{ charset.to_a[rand(charset.size)] }.join
    end

    def construct()
        base_uri = 'FIREBASE_URL'
        file = File.open("FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS", "rb")
        firebase = Firebase::Client.new(base_uri, file.read)
        Conekta.locale = :es
        Conekta.api_key = 'MY_KEY'
        @response = firebase.get('users', nil)
        @client = Savon.client(wsdl: 'MY_URL', ntlm: ["user", "pass"] , :convert_request_keys_to => :camelcase )
        @client_mysql = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :password => "", :database => "masaldo_api")
    end

    def get_comision()
        last_validity = @client_mysql.query("SELECT comision * 100 as comision FROM configuration")
        last_validity.each do |validityr|
            @comision = validityr["comision"]
        end   
    end

    def create_transaction(sku, token, phone, userid, card)
        validity = @client_mysql.query("SELECT precio * 100 as precio_total, vigencia, descripcion, precio as precio_base FROM bluesoft_services_validity WHERE sku='#{sku}'")
        validity.each do |row|
            @vigencia = row["vigencia"]
            @descipcion = row["descripcion"]
            @precio = row["precio_total"]
            @precio_base = row["precio_base"].to_i
        end
        if @vigencia.to_i > 0
            last_current = @client_mysql.query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE number='#{phone}' ORDER BY trandate DESC LIMIT 1")                             
            last_current.each do |last|
                @trandate = last["trandate"]
                @trandate_result = @trandate.strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")                        
            end              
        end
        @last_with_validty = (@trandate + (@vigencia).to_i.day).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 
        @today = (Time.now).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 
        if @last_with_validty == @today
           conekta_charges = Conekta::Order.create({
                            :currency => "MXN",
                            :customer_info => {
                                :customer_id => user['customer_id']
                        },
                        :line_items => [{
                            :name => @descipcion,
                            :unit_price => @precio.to_i,
                            :quantity => 1
                        },
                        {
                            :name => 'Comision de Recarga',
                            :unit_price => @comision.to_i,
                            :quantity => 1
                        }],
                            :charges => [{
                                :payment_method => {
                                    :type => "card",
                                    :payment_source_id => user['fav_card']
                            }
                        }]
                    })
                    if conekta_charges['payment_status'] == 'paid'
                        begin  
                            response = @client.call(:venta, message: { 'sku' => 'TELCPA100MXN', 'fechaLocal' => '20180117 14:55:00', 'referencia' => '818181818181', 'monto' => '100', 'id_cadena' => '30', 'id_tienda' => '30', 'id_terminal' => '1', 'folio' => 'LUCOPCIHOW' })                        
                            parameters = response.body
                            parameters.each do |response, data|
                                if data[:return][:respuesta][:codigo_respuesta] == 0
                                    puts data[:return][:respuesta]
                                else
                                    puts data[:return][:respuesta]
                                end
                            end 
                        rescue Exception => e  
                            puts e.message  
                            puts e.backtrace.inspect  
                        end 
                    end
        end  
    end

    def init()
        threads = []        
        hash = @response.body
        hash.each do |token , user|
            threads <<  Thread.new do 
                #Check if user is current for transaction if not need to check agenda
                if user['is_current']                   
                    self.create_transaction(user['sku'], token, user['phoneNumber'], user['customer_id'], user['fav_card'])   
                    user['addressBook'].each do |userid , user_address_book|
                        if user['is_current']   
                            replacements = { '+521' => '' }
                            phone_number =  user_address_book['phoneNumber'].gsub(Regexp.union(replacements.keys), replacements)                                                    
                            self.create_transaction(user_address_book['sku'], token, phone_number, user['customer_id'], user_address_book['fav_card'])
                        end
                    end
                end
            end            
        end
        threads.each { |t| t.join  }  
    end
end

classCron = Cron.new()
classCron.construct()
classCron.get_comision()
classCron.init()
```

Regards

Comment: It's worth noting that if you're just getting started with Ruby the "new" hash notation is often less clutter: `Mysql2::Client.new(host: 'localhost', username: ...)` where `{ x: y }` is equivalent to `{ :x => y }`.

Comment: I made it, thanks.
any advice about the open connection of mysql, and the threads are right?

Comment: You'll also want to omit empty arguments, like `new()` becomes simply `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing multi-threaded code in Ruby you'll need to be careful about not sharing resources like database connections between threads unless the driver makes it abundantly clear that kind of operation is supported. The ones I'm familiar with don't, and Mysql2 is not thread safe that way.

You can use `Thread[:db]` to store a local database connection per-thread, like:

```
def db
  Thread.current[:db] ||= Mysql2::Client.new(...)
end
```

Where then you can refer to it like this:

```
db.query(...)
```

That will automatically instantiate the connection as required.

It's worth noting that `mysql2` is a low-level driver and isn't very pleasant to use. A higher level abstraction like [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) provides a number of significant benefits: Migrations, (optional) model layer, and a very robust query builder with support for placeholder values and easy escaping.

Comment: thanks, when all the threads are finished i suppose that i need to close the connection?

Comment: Unless you're creating and destroying a lot of threads that's not normally an issue, but if you are you should make an effort to close the connection on thread termination.

Comment: @IvanOlshansky That should have been `Thread.current[:db]` and fixed. Thanks for pointing that out.